# How to Ruby scope a complex query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

[image: Simple table layout]

My models look like

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :meeting
end

class Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :messages
end
```

data might look something like

**meetings**
1, Meeting A, 2012-12-10 08:00
2, Meeting B, 2012-12-08 07:00

**messages**
32,2,Good, 2012-11-20 08:00
33,1,Horrible, 2012-11-18 07:00
34,2,Bad, 2012-09-23 08:00
35,1,Great, 2012-08-18 07:00
36,2,Dreadful, 2012-05-20 08:00
37,1,SoSo, 2012-04-18 07:00

I want a collection of Messages where only the max(created_at), group(meeting_id) is returned....
 
so using my sample data as a example would return a Message collection of only 2 rows
32,2,Good, 2012-11-20 08:00
33,1,Horrible, 2012-11-18 07:00

Answer (score 0):

A scope defined in `Meeting` model for most recent messages would be:

```
# app/models/meeting.rb
scope :most_recent, lambda { joins(:messages).order('messages.created_at desc') }
```

Further down in your question you mention you want to use `Message.most_recent.joins(:meeting)` then for this you'd add the following scope in your `Message` model:

```
# app/models/message.rb
scope :most_recent, lambda { order('created_at desc') }
```

**Update:**

Try the following query to select `messages` grouped by `meeting_id` with latest `created_at`.  This should give you what you're expecting:

```
latest_by_meetings = Message.select('max(id) as max_id, max(created_at) as max_created_at').group(:meeting_id)
Message.where(id: latest_by_meetings.collect(&:max_id).order('created_at desc')
```

So, your scope may look like:

```
# app/models/message.rb
scope :most_recent, lambda { where(id: select('max(id) as max_message_id').group(:meeting_id).collect(&:max_message_id)).order('created_at desc') }
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer my question but I think I might've done a bad job explaining myself...
Whatever activerecord call I make needs to return the all of the Meetings and ONLY the most recent Message for each meeting record
Am I making sense?

Comment: @bopritchard, that's probably the part I misunderstood.  Aren't you saying that you need `Meeting.first.messages.order('messages.created_at desc')`?

Comment: sorry for the confusion...I probably made it more complicated than it needed to be...how about this?...  
a collection of Messages where only the max(created_at) group(meeting_id) is returned....  
so using my sample data would return a Message collection of  

[32,2,Good, 2012-11-20 08:00]  
[33,1,Horrible, 2012-11-18 07:00]  
thank you again

Comment: @bopritchard, apologies for the delay in replying.  Please see the updates.  I believe that query should give you what you are expecting.